# Resetting a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'file.php';
}, 115000);
```

How can I, via a .click function, reset the counter midway through the countdown?

Comment: You can probably use an existing debounce implementation.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You can store a reference to that timeout, and then call [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) on that reference.

```
// in the example above, assign the result
var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(...);

// in your click function, call clearTimeout
window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

// then call setTimeout again to reset the timer
timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(...);
```

Comment: So strange that there isn't a `.clear()` on the timeout object itself.

Comment: @Cort3z that's because `window.setTimeout` returns a number (the timer's ID) and not a "timeout object".

Comment: Yes @DanO : strange that setTimeout doesn't return a Timeout object. In a NodeJS context it does.

Answer (score 37):

clearTimeout() and feed the reference of the setTimeout, which will be a number. Then re-invoke it:

```
var initial;

function invocation() {
    alert('invoked')
    initial = window.setTimeout( 
    function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
    }, 5000);
}

invocation();

document.body.onclick = function() {
    alert('stopped')
    clearTimeout( initial )
    // re-invoke invocation()
}
```

In this example, if you don't click on the body element in 5 seconds the background color will be black.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout

Note: setTimeout and clearTimeout are not ECMAScript native methods, but Javascript methods of the global window namespace.

Answer (score 15):

You will have to remember the timeout "Timer", cancel it, then restart it:

```
g_timer = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    startTimer();
});

function startTimer() {
    g_timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = 'file.php';
    }, 115000);
}

function onClick() {
    clearTimeout(g_timer);
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Interesting that this option has been ignored. The others all seem to require the timer internal function to be duplicated, which is less than dry and painful if there are more than a few lines of code to maintain twice...

Answer (score 10):

```
var myTimer = setTimeout(..., 115000);
something.click(function () {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    myTimer = setTimeout(..., 115000);
});
```

Something along those lines!

Answer (score 10):

For **NodeJS** it's super simple:

```
const timeout = setTimeout(...);

timeout.refresh();
```

From the docs:

> **timeout.refresh()**
>
> Sets the timer's start time to the current time, and reschedules the timer to call its callback at the previously specified duration adjusted to the current time. This is useful for refreshing a timer without allocating a new JavaScript object.

But it **won't work in JavaScript** because in browser `setTimeout()` returns a number, not an object.

Answer (score 4):

i know this is an old thread but i came up with this today

```
var timer       = []; //creates a empty array called timer to store timer instances
var afterTimer = function(timerName, interval, callback){
    window.clearTimeout(timer[timerName]); //clear the named timer if exists
    timer[timerName] = window.setTimeout(function(){ //creates a new named timer 
        callback(); //executes your callback code after timer finished
    },interval); //sets the timer timer
}
```

and you invoke using

```
afterTimer('<timername>string', <interval in milliseconds>int, function(){
   your code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This timer will fire a "Hello" alertbox after 30 seconds. However, everytime you click the reset timer button it clears the timerHandle then re-sets it again. Once it's fired, the game ends.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timerHandle = setTimeout("alert('Hello')",3000);
    function resetTimer() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("alert('Hello')",3000);
    }
</script>

<body>
    <button onclick="resetTimer()">Reset Timer</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var redirectionDelay;
function startRedirectionDelay(){
    redirectionDelay = setTimeout(redirect, 115000);
}
function resetRedirectionDelay(){
    clearTimeout(redirectionDelay);
}

function redirect(){
    location.href = 'file.php';
}

// in your click >> fire those
resetRedirectionDelay();
startRedirectionDelay();
```

---

#### here is an elaborated example for what's really going on http://jsfiddle.net/ppjrnd2L/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

    (function(){

        var pthis = this;
        this.mseg = 115000;
        this.href = 'file.php'

        this.setTimer = function() { 
            return (window.setTimeout( function() {window.location.href = this.href;}, this.mseg));
        };
        this.timer = pthis.setTimer();

        this.clear = function(ref) { clearTimeout(ref.timer); ref.setTimer(); };
        $(window.document).click( function(){pthis.clear.apply(pthis, [pthis])} );

    })();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To reset the timer, you would need to set and clear out the timer variable

```
$time_out_handle = 0;
window.clearTimeout($time_out_handle);
$time_out_handle = window.setTimeout( function(){---}, 60000 );
```

Comment: Argh, I advise against using php style variable names in javascript.  yes, it'll work, but my God, it's confusing.