# Reset javascript page refresh value after jquery ajax action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

If certain conditions are met I use a jquery ajax query to display a message on a page. When I click close on the message it disappears. I also have some javascript on the same page that automatically refreshes the page after 30 seconds. What I'm trying to do is when I click close on the message it resets the automatic refresh back to 30 seconds.

Comment: I want to note that I want to reset the automatic refresh back to 30 without refreshing the page.

Comment: Without an actual code it's only one option available - use voodoo magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried this?

```
mytimeout = setTimeout("alert('refreshing page')", 30000);
```

And then on button click do:

```
clearTimeout(mytimeout);
mytimeout = setTimeout("alert('refreshing page')", 30000);
```

Comment: No, I hadn't tried that, and it works! Thanks! I was actually searching more on on and found this as well [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout].