# How to reset setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

i have this action after click:

```
  remote_top.on('click',function(){
        if (program_changer_block.css('display','block')){
            var g_timer = null;
            clearTimeout(g_timer);
            setTimeout(function(){
                program_changer_block.fadeOut();
            }, 5100);
        }
        else if (program_changer_block.css('display','none')){
            setTimeout(function(){
                program_changer_block.fadeIn();
            }, 300);
        }
   });
```

What i'm trying to do is clear timeout after each click. Now after some fast clicks my blocks hide after 5100ms calculated from the first click. How to restart this timeout after each click? Something is wrong, can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout

Comment: Make `g_timer` scope more global and assign it the return value of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setTimeout()` function returns the *timeout ID*. Just store it in your `g_timer` variable and also make it global:

```
  var g_timer;
  remote_top.on('click',function(){
        if (program_changer_block.css('display','block')){
            clearTimeout(g_timer);
            g_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                program_changer_block.fadeOut();
            }, 5100);
        }
        else if (program_changer_block.css('display','none')){
            g_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                program_changer_block.fadeIn();
            }, 300);
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried control directly queue with clearQueue and delay ?

```
remote_top.on('click',function(){
    if(program_changer_block.css('display','block')){
        program_changer_block.stop(true,true).delay(5100).fadeOut();
    }
    else if(program_changer_block.css('display','none')){
        program_changer_block.stop(true,true).delay(300).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

the first true in stop() mean .clearQueue()