# How to clear setTimeout on jQuery mouseover #id

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

This is my current code to run the series of setTimeout functions. How do I stop these when either the mouse moves, or is over a certain element?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
  clicky()    
  function clicky() {
    setTimeout(function () {jQuery('#1500').trigger('click');}, 3000);
    setTimeout(function () {jQuery('#1990').trigger('click');}, 6000);
    setTimeout(function () {jQuery('#2010').trigger('click');}, 9000);
    setTimeout(function () {jQuery('#battle').trigger('click');}, 12000);
    setTimeout(function () {
      jQuery('#water').trigger('click');clicky()
    }, 15000);
  }    
});
```

Comment: Save the `timeoutId` and clear it by doing `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`

Comment: do you want to restart it again later

Comment: Yes, I do. I added the timeoutID and that's working. When I mouseover the area, the alert works, but the clearTimeout isn't working...

I want the timeout to stop when the user moves their mouse and on continue when they don't. It's an odd UX, I know.

Comment: @wayne-m I just posted an example. Let me know if you have any questions or concerns about the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially need to save a reference to your timeouts so that they can be cleared when you need them to be. In the following example, I just used an object so that you could specify which timeout you wanted to affect, if desired.

Here's a working fiddle that will clear the timeouts on hover, then reset them when the mouse leaves: http://jsfiddle.net/6tQ4M/2/

And the code:

```
$(function(){
    var timeouts = {};

    function setTimeouts () {
        timeouts['#1500'] = specifyTimeout('#1500', 3000);
        timeouts['#1990'] = specifyTimeout('#1990', 6000);
        timeouts['#2010'] = specifyTimeout('#2010', 9000);
        timeouts['#battle'] = specifyTimeout('#battle', 12000);
        timeouts['#water'] = specifyTimeout('#water', 15000, function(){
            console.log('reset the timeouts');
            clearTimeouts();
            setTimeouts();
        });
    }

    function clearTimeouts () {
        for(var key in timeouts){
            if(timeouts.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                clearTimeout(timeouts[key]);
                delete timeouts[key];
            }
        }
    }

    function specifyTimeout (id, time, callback) {
        return setTimeout(function(){
            $(id).trigger('click');
            if(callback){
                callback();
            }
        }, time);
    }

    $('a').on('click', function(){
        $('#projects').append('clicky clicky!');
    });

    $('#map').on('mouseover', clearTimeouts);
    $('#map').on('mouseleave', setTimeouts);

    setTimeouts();

});
```

Let me know if you have any questions about the code at all!

Comment: Thank you, Matt! That looks like exactly what I need. minus the append ;)

Comment: Happy to help. :) I just put that `append()` there so you could see that it was running. Feel free to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: @wayne-m also, open up your console to see the callback function firing. :) You'll want to delete that line, too, or IE may explode.

Comment: Yep, definitely. That was perfect! I for sure got rid of the console.log too, IE should explode however.

Answer (score 2):

Your setTimeout needs to be defined to a variable, so that it can be cleared by passing to `clearTimeout()`. Something like:

```
var interval = setTimeout(function() {
    //msc
}, 8000);
window.clearTimeout(interval);
```

Comment: Hey @wayne-m, no problem, what does your code look like now? Could you set up a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: this is the working functionality www.waynemarci.com/indiancountry

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to what you ordered, when you hover an area, the `setTimeOut` should be fired, and when you are out of this region, the `setTimeOut` should be reset.

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var timeoutHandle;

$('#map').mouseover(function(event){
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
});

$('#map').mouseout(function(event){
    timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello alert!"); }, 2000);
});
```

Basically you should keep a reference to the `setTimeOut`, in this case the variable is `timeoutHandle`, call `clearTimeOut` on mouse over and call setTimeOut again to reset the timer.

Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bernardo_pacheco/RBnpp/4/

The same principle can be used for more than one `setTimeOut` timer.

You can see more technical details here:

[Resetting a setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP wants. On mouseover, the timeouts need to be cleared, not set.