# reset javascript timer on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code:

```
var logout_warning = 6000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#logout_warning').reveal();
    }, logout_warning)
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        alert("logout");
        //location.href = "/login/logout.php?url=/index.php?r=inactivity";
    }, logout_warning*2)
});
```

that displays a warning after 6000ms then redirects to a URL to logout a user after 12000ms

I have this a href link:

```
<a href="" onClick="ResetLogoutTimer();" class="acceptButton" style="margin-top:114px; margin-right:120px;">Stay Logged In</a>
```

which i want to reset the time on click to stop the user from being logged out, i created this function but im not sure what to put inside it

```
function ResetLogoutTimer() {

}
```

Comment: [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1472717/3444240)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var log_outer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                alert("logout");
                //location.href = "/login/logout.php?url=/index.php?r=inactivity";
               }, logout_warning*2)


function ResetLogoutTimer() {
  window.clearTimeout(log_outer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for poor English, its my second language.

You should try:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('#logout_warning').reveal();
    }, logout_warning)
```

and than

```
function ResetLogoutTimer() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

The docs for it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

One last thing, do not use w3c schools for learning javascript (the docs are not complete , instead use mdn site https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/JavaScript