# Go to page after 10 minutes of no interaction

Tags: javascript, timer

I am creating a local website (only one person will be able to interact with it at a time) to be displayed on a big touch screen at an office I am working at.

The client wants to have a screensaver appear over the website after 10 minutes of no interaction. I am creating that in Flash Actionscript 3.0. There are seven pages and seven screensavers. I tried to persuade them to have just the one screensaver which would make my life a whole lot easier but the client insists.

Is it possible to write a JavaScript statement that says

> "If no click is registered after 10 minutes, then go to this URL
>   (Where the Flash screensaver will be)".

I would share my links for a further explanation but some of the content is confidential at this stage.

If it is possible I will try my hand at writing the .js code, and update this section, but I thought I would check if it is even possible first.

I have tried to write the JavaScript for this but I can't get my alert box to appear, any ideas?

```
  function redirect(){
  window.location.href = "autoplay/index.html";
  }
  var initial=setTimeout(redirect,6000);
  function click()
  {
  clearTimeout( initial );
  alert("helo");
  initial=setTimeout(redirect,12000);
  }
```

Comment: Use a `timeout` of 10 minutes that is reset with every click.

Comment: Easily possible. You will need a variable. A `setInterval` and a minute of work.

Comment: Are you sure clicks are the only thing you want to use to define "interaction"? What about typing or scrolling?

Comment: Why do you need javascript, if the project is actionscript? Is it possible you could handle those screensavers from within your flash app?

Comment: There is no scroll and no text box so the click function is all I need. The site is a mix of Jquery, html, css and Adobe Flash, so I can't just use Actionscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it is working!

```
/* The redirect to autoplay page function */
 function redirect(){
 window.location.href = "autoplay/index.html";
 }
 var initial=setTimeout(redirect,6000);

 $(document).click(function(event) { 
 clearTimeout( initial );
 initial=setTimeout(redirect,12000); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using [underscore's debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

```
var redirect=_.debounce(function() {
    location.href='myscreensaver.com/url';
},600000);

jQuery(document).on('click',function() {
  // trigger click
  redirect();
});
```

everytime a click happens, redirect gets called. Underscore debounce method won't call the redirection function unless X time (600.000 miliseconds in this case) pass between function calls. This means that clicks that happen in between do reset the debounce timer and it has to start over.

Answer (score 1):

Use a setTimeout with a timeout of 10 min

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

On a every click you have to reset it.
Some info here:[Resetting a setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout)