# How can I reset a settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried the answer here: [Resetting a setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I'm building a catalog viewer using Owl Carousel. I have a function set to go off on the afterMove event handler that shows what page the user is on. It displays the page counter and then sets a timeout to have it fadeout after 1 second. Probably is lots of people go through pages faster than once per second. So, I need to reset the timeout if the function gets called again.

```
function showCounter(){
     var $counter = $('#counter');
     //clear timeout
     window.clearTimeout(timeout);
     //Display counter
     $counter.show();
     //set timeout
     var timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
         $counter.fadeOut(500);
     }, 1000);
}
```

But window.clearTimeout(timeout) doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why

Thanks

Comment: `timeout` isn't even defined in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var timeout` inside the function makes `timeout` local to the function; thus, every time you call `showCounter`, `timeout` is `undefined`. Move the variable declaration out of the function:

```
var timeout;
function showCounter() {
  // ...
  timeout = // NO VAR! ...
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Further explanation: whilst it may look like `timeout` is not defined prior to the `var timeout = ...` line, thanks to a "feature" of JS called [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), it is as if you had a line `var timeout;` at the very top of your `showCounter()` function.