# DataTables Server-side Processing for large JSON files with dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a process that generates a JSON file with a large amount of entries and then gets read into a Datatable and displayed to the user. I'm having trouble figuring out how to transform my current method of creating the datatable to allow for server side processing. I am trying to avoid the entire file loading before displaying in the browser.

JS

```
<script>
function MakeColumnHeaderHtml(columnHeaderNames) {

  var table_head = '<thead class="table-header"><tr>';

  $.each(columnHeaderNames, function (data, value) {

    table_head += '<th>';
    table_head += value;
    table_head += '</th>';

  });

  table_head += '</thead></tr>';

  return table_head;
}

// this will provide the definition of the table
function getDatatableDef(columnDef) {

  var datatableFormat = {
    columns: columnDef,
    paging:true,
    info:false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false
  };

  return datatableFormat;
}

//ajax call to get the data from json file
function getTableData() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "1595003621_data.json",
      method: "Get"
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

  //1. call the api
  getTableData().done(function (records) {

    // get header name using key names
    var headerName = Object.keys(records[0]);

    // build html for table headers
    var headerHtml = MakeColumnHeaderHtml(headerName);

    var columns = [];

    //append the table header
    $('#exampleTable').append(headerHtml);

    //create a clumn definition
    for (var i = 0; i < headerName.length; i++) {
      columns.push({ "data": headerName[i] });
    }

    //initialize the DataTable
    var datatableInstance = $('#exampleTable').DataTable(getDatatableDef(columns));

    //Now the last step to add data
    datatableInstance.rows.add(records).draw();

  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Just to check, when implementing `serverSide: true` for the first time: Are you familiar with [the JSON structure](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) that your server is expected to use when sending data to DataTables? And the [related JSON structure](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) that DataTables automatically sends to the server whenever there is a paging/sorting/filtering request? Those can be good places to start.

Comment: _avoid the entire file loading before displaying in the browser_  - A key point here is that with server-side processing, you no longer send the entire data set to the browser in one go - you send manageable subsets (maybe 1,000 rows, out of your total 1 million rows) each time.

Comment: @andrewjames the JSON structure is unknown as the file is generated by a query that is ran against multiple databases. Could be different every time

Comment: Yes, agreed - that's the "dynamic columns" of the question's title. That requirement can co-exist with server-side processing. These may be worth looking at: [server-side example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801535/how-can-i-load-a-set-number-of-rows-from-a-table-on-pageload-and-only-load-furth/60804184#60804184) and [dynamic JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713887/query-datatable-from-rest-api-without-pre-defining-the-table-in-html/61718192#61718192).

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this old question got no practical answer yet. I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801535) (also mentioned among the comments above as "server-side example") and experimented a bit using node.js as a server, and here's what I got: a working example. I'd strongly recommend reading that original post before getting into my codes. I'm basically making a realization out of what's written in that post:

The data: (put this at the root of where you have the working directory of node.js service)

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"widget_1",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 1"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"widget_2",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 2"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"widget_3",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 3"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"widget_4",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 4"
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "name":"widget_5",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 5"
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "name":"widget_6",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 6"
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "name":"widget_7",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 7"
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "name":"widget_8",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 8"
   },
   {
      "id":9,
      "name":"widget_9",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 9"
   },
   {
      "id":10,
      "name":"widget_10",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 10"
   },
   {
      "id":11,
      "name":"widget_11",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 11"
   },
   {
      "id":12,
      "name":"widget_12",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 12"
   },
   {
      "id":13,
      "name":"widget_13",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 13"
   },
   {
      "id":14,
      "name":"widget_14",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 14"
   },
   {
      "id":15,
      "name":"widget_15",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 15"
   },
   {
      "id":16,
      "name":"widget_16",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 16"
   },
   {
      "id":17,
      "name":"widget_17",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 17"
   },
   {
      "id":18,
      "name":"widget_18",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 18"
   },
   {
      "id":19,
      "name":"widget_19",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 19"
   },
   {
      "id":20,
      "name":"widget_20",
      "description":"This is a description for widget 20"
   }
]
```

The HTML: (put this under `your working directory`/public)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <div style="margin: 20px;">
        <div id='pageinfo' style='display:none'></div>
        <table class="display dataTable cell-border" id="demo" style="width:100%"></table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
           var table = $('#demo').DataTable({
             serverSide: true,
             ajax: {
               url: 'http://localhost:3000/data',
               data: $('#pageinfo').text(), //post pagination parameters to server
               type: 'POST'
             },
             columns: [
               { title: 'ID',
                 data: 'id' },
               { title: 'Name',
                 data: 'name' },
               { title: 'Description',
                 data: 'description' }
             ],
             lengthMenu: [5, 10, 20],
             pageLength: 5
           });
           function getinfo(){
               var info = table.page.info();
               return info;
           }
           $('.dataTables_wrapper').on('click',function(e){
               var info = table.page.info();
               $('#pageinfo').text(JSON.stringify(info)) //get the pagination parameters
           })
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the server:

```js
    const fs = require('fs');
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("data.json", 'utf8'));
    
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
      extended: true
    }));
    
    app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.post('/data', function(req, res){
        var resp = {"recordsTotal": 20,"recordsFiltered": 20,"start":0,"length":5}
        if(req.body.start){
            resp.draw = JSON.parse(req.body.draw);
            resp.data = data.slice(JSON.parse(req.body.start),
                                    JSON.parse(req.body.start)+JSON.parse(req.body.length));
        }else{
            resp.draw = 1;
            resp.data = data.slice(resp.start,resp.start+resp.length);
        }
        res.end(JSON.stringify(resp))
    })
    
    
    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('listening on port 3000');
    });
```

Then you'd be able to just start the server, and browse the result at http://localhost:3000/static/dtable.html

Read through these codes, or probably dig in to a few intermediate outputs, and you'll have a better idea of how DataTable works under a minimum setup for server-side processing.