# use onmousemove to reset setTimeout() to start over again（・・？

Tags: javascript

when mouse moves, the timer function cancelled =="
but i actually want it to count from the beginning instead.

```
function w()
{
    if (parent.C.location == "http://119.247.250.128/wasyoku/home/prime.html")
    {   parent.C.location = "weather.html";
        wTout = setTimeout(function(){ parent.C.location = "prime.html"; }, wT);
    }
    else { parent.C.location = "prime.html"; clearTimeout(wTout); }
}

document.onmousemove.clearTimeout(wTout);
```

do i really need to setTimeout again（・・？

```
wTout = setTimeout(function(){ parent.C.location = "prime.html"; }, wT);
```

Comment: Yes, you have to set the timer again.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you clear the timeout you have to set it again.
Another thing you can do is set a variable as the last time you moved the mouse and on the ontimeout you can set another settimeout if you moved the mouse in XX seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
var sto = null;

function myTimeout() {
    window.clearTimeout(sto);
    sto = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("setTimeout's working");
    }, 2000);
}

someElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    myTimeout();
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/zx6xgwg0/)