# JS - Set delay between sending AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on building a search feature into my site. To do this I have a search bar which sends an AJAX request to my server each time a user types something. The server will in turn send back the items which match the search.

The only problem with this currently is that if a user types "a" and then "b" what it will send is:

`a`

`ab`

To counter this I have found `setTimeout` which delays when the user enters a search; however, currently it is only delaying when the strings fire (i.e. waits 0.75 seconds before sending `a` and then waits 0.75 seconds before sending `ab`).

### Here's the JS:

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(function(e) {
    var timeoutID  = setTimeout(searchRequest, 750, $(e.currentTarget).val());
  });

function searchRequest(str) {
  if (str.length > 0) {
    console.log('search request initalized | sending: ', str);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST', 'code to send here', true);
    xhttp.send(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you try jquery autocomplete?

Comment: Ok, you described the problem, but you have not asked a question.

Comment: Remove `$(e.currentTarget).val()` from `setTimeout` and add `var str = $('#searchBox').val();` to `searchRequest`. This is the case when you don't need closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a debounce function.

Here's the basic JavaScript debounce function (as taken from Underscore.js):

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

You can use it to debounce click:

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(debounce(function(e) {
    searchRequest$(e.currentTarget).val());
}, 750));
```

Comment: thank you! I don't understand it but it works! Now it's time to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear thew timeout to make it work. Have a look on this link ;) [Resetting a setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout)

Basically, when the user added a letter, you check if you already defined a timeout. If you defined a timeout you clear it. Then you reset the timeout. Something like that

```js
var yourTimeout;

function sendInfo(info){
  if (yourTimeout != undefined) 
    clearTimeout(yourTimeout);
  
  yourTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    //do something
  }, 500);
}
```

In your case, the sendInfo function is the keyup handler, and you call searchRequest in the timeout like you already did ;)

Hope it helps