# need help (javascript/jquery timer function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a timer of 2min, which starts on click on btn. If you click on btn it works perfectly, and after completing 2min again click on btn it works perfectly.

problem: if user click btn before completing the 2min the timer reintiate itself and start timer parallel two times or n times.

I need help that on every click timer should start from beginning and run only one timer.

Please see "Run Code Snippet" for more clarity.

```js
$('.timer-btn').off('click').on('click', myfunction);

            function myfunction(){
              var countdown = 2 * 60 * 1000;
              var timerId = setInterval(function(){
              countdown -= 1000;
              var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
              //var sec = Math.floor(countdown - (min * 60 * 1000));  // wrong
              var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);  //correct

              if (countdown <= 0) {
                 alert("30 min!");
                 clearInterval(timerId);
                 //doSomething();
              } else {
                 $("#timerDiv").html(min + " : " + sec);
              }
              }, 1000);
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="timerDiv"> timer here </div>
<div class="timer-btn"> Click Me </div>
```

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the previous interval before starting a new one.

```
var timerId;

function myfunction(){
    var countdown = 2 * 60 * 1000;
    timerId = clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = setInterval(function(){
        countdown -= 1000;
        var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
        //var sec = Math.floor(countdown - (min * 60 * 1000));  // wrong
        var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);  //correct

        if (countdown <= 0) {
            alert("30 min!");
            clearInterval(timerId);
            //doSomething();
        } else {
            $("#timerDiv").html(min + " : " + sec);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

$('.timer-btn').off('click').on('click', myfunction);
```

Comment: thanks for your time and effort. but its still behaving same. click two or more times on button and see.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsbin.com/miqegigezo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes its working fine. Than you!

Comment: Happy to help :)