# Reset JavaScript timer on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, session-timeout

I have an issue with my asp.net page that displays session timeout warning even when users are entering data intermittently. We have session timeout warning set in Master page as a company policy:

```
 var sessionTimeoutWarning = 45;
 sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout('SessionWarning()', sessionTimeoutWarning * 60 * 1000);
```

On the aspx page, I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            $('a').filter(function (index) { return $(this).text() === "Month to Date"; }).click();

        };

        function ValidateAndShowPopup() {
            if (Page_ClientValidate('grpSubmit')) {
                SubmitF();

            }
        }
```

I have the button inside update panel:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitReport" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitReport_Click" ValidationGroup="grpSubmit" OnClientClick="ValidateAndShowPopup()" CssClass="btn" />
```

The only two solutions are either to refresh the page on button click (which I dont want to do), Or to reset the javascript timer on page.
Please guide how to reset the javascript timer variable on button click.

Comment: `clearTimeout(sessionWarningTimer);`

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1472705/6139866)

Comment: asp:Button  cannot handle both onClick and onClientClick events (elegantly).
If you are certain you don't want to Re-Post the page then you should remove the onClick Event.
I would however, remove the OnClientClick and run your timer reset function using registerStartUpscript

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were trying to do?

```js
var session;

function startSessionTimer() {
 session = setTimeout(function(){ 
     alert("Session Expired"); 
    }, 2000);
}

function stopSessionTimer() {
    clearTimeout(session);
    alert("Session Expiration Stopped"); 
}

// Immediately start session timer
// startSessionTimer();
```

```html
<button onclick="startSessionTimer()">Start Timer</button>
<button onclick="stopSessionTimer()">Stop Timer</button>
```