# When mouse stops moving in element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I'm trying to achieve: when my mouse **is moving** then do this, but when it **stops moving** for like half a second then do that, but when it **starts to move again** then do that.
This is my temporary jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.test').mouseenter(function(){

    $(this).mousemove(function(){
      $(this).css({
        'background-color' : '#666',
        'cursor' : 'none'
      });
    });
  });

  $('.test').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css({
      'background-color' : '#777',
      'cursor' : 'default'
    });
  });
});
```

And I have absolutely no idea how to do that, basically my code does this: when you enter an element with a mouse and your mouse is moving inside that element then apply this CSS and when your mouse leaves the element then apply this CSS, but when mouse is inside that element and it stops moving for some period of time then do this <- I can't figure the last bit out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understood that you want to detect the mouse movements over a particular element.

To achieve this, you need to use the `mousemove` event... There is no `mousefroze` event, sadly!

So you will use a `setTimeout()` and will constantly clear its callback while the mouse moves. Since that event fires multiple times on a single slight movement, you can set the delay quite tight. So it should be accurate.

**The setTimeout callback will execute only when the mouse will stop moving.** And that is the whole *"trick"*.

About delays... I think that `100` ms is the lowest accurate value. Less than that will create flickering on "slow" user moves.

The `mouseenter` is not really usefull here, because it is overridden by the mousemove event right after (because when the mouse enters... it also moves!). But the `mouseleave` or `mouseout` is really usefull to restore the element's original state and clear the timeout too... Because the mouse won't be moving over your element does'nt mean it doesn't move at all. So you have to clear that when leaving.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var test = $('#test');
  var moveTimer;

  test.on("mouseout",function(){
    $(this).css({
      'background-color' : 'white',
    }).text("");
    clearTimeout(moveTimer);
  });

  test.on("mousemove",function(){
    console.log("I'm moving!");

    clearTimeout(moveTimer);
    moveTimer = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("I stopped moving!");
      test.css({
        'background-color' : 'red',
      }).text("The mouse is not moving.");
    },100)

    $(this).css({
      'background-color' : 'blue',
    }).text("Movement detected...");
  });
});
```

```css
#test{
  margin:50px;
  border:2px solid black;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yKdKzB?editors=1111)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for timeouts. In a similar project, I used something like this:

```
var timer;

function active() {
    // Apply active styles
}

function inactive() {
    // Apply inactive styles
}

$('.test').mousemove(function(){
    active(); // Apply active styles
    clearTimeout(timer); // Reset the timer
    timer = setTimeout(out, 500);
});
```

Once you move the mouse over the area, that launches a timer that resets every mouse move. If the timer is ever allowed to expire, the user's gone inactive and we run whatever code we like.

Comment: I don't tested your code but you need to rethinking about the logic of it .. how can the `timer` updates when mouse stop while you make the `timer = setTimeout(out, 500);` update when mousemove .. I think `timer = setTimeout(out, 500);` after `clearTimeout(timer);` is useless

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're saying, but that code clears the old timer, then creates a new one. setTimeout returns an integer ID for the timer, it doesn't contain the timer itself. If we don't [clear it first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout#1472717), it will fire. Essentially, it resets it. I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/126451/) to show how it works.

Comment: i'm really sorry about this its my bad .. me need to rethinking about your code .. you're totally right .. anyway you can get the demo from jsfiddle and show it here in a snippet .. Have a great day :) and good answer +1

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it doesn't seem to work when I apply this in my code. I filled the functions with my CSS, but logically it should work.

Comment: If you're using the function names "in" and "out" those should probably be changed since "in" is an operator in JavaScript. Went and edited my post so that they're "active" and "inactive" now.

Answer (score 1):

So I was just googling. This is the answer:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var countdown;
    $('.test').hover(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.test').css({
          'background-color' : '#666',
          'cursor' : 'none'
        });
        cursor();
      }, 2000);
    }, function(e){
      $('.test').css({
          'background-color' : '#777',
      'cursor' : 'default'
      });
    });

    $('.test').mousemove(function() {
      $('.test').css({
        'background-color' : '#777',
        'cursor' : 'default'
        });
        cursor();
      });
      function cursor() {
        countdown = setTimeout(function() {
          $('.test').css({
            'background-color' : '#666',
            'cursor' : 'none'
          });
        }, 2000);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: You've got a lot of duplicate code in there. Consider using some functions to tidy up a bit.

Comment: Yeah I know, I will do it, but now I was just focusing on the main problem, the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This may deviate from your current code, but I think CSS is more appropriate here than JavaScript.

```
.test {
    background-color:#666;
}

.test:hover {
    background-color:#777;
    cursor:none;
}
```

These lines of CSS should perform the exact same thing without the complication. Note that in your example, for every pixel the mouse moves, the css is set once more. And since you are not removing the event handler on mouse out, the event is actually ran multiple times.