# Interrupt and Reset set Timeout - Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, event-listener, cleartimeout

I have the following issue: I am currently working on a Chatbot that is supposed to simulate an exam situation. Therefore I let it ask questions and the User should have an x amount of time in order to answer the question. Once the time is up, the Bot is supposed to ask the next question. However, once the student has sent the answer ( by pressing the enter key -> because that is the only way to continue the conversation) the bot should interrupt & reset the timer as well and ask a new question.

I have the developed the following concept

It seems to work once - so basically skipping from question 1 to question 2 but after another Enter event, it returns the next two questions and so on.

What am I don't wrong here?

```js
const Question1E = " 1-This is the easy Question";
const Question1H = " 1-This is the hard Question";
const Question2E = " 2-This is the easy Question";
const Question2H = " 2-This is the hard Question";
const Question3E = " 3-This is the easy Question";
const Question3H = " 3-This is the hard Question";
const Question4E = " 4-This is the easy Question";
const Question4H = " 4-This is the hard Question";
const Question5E = " 5-This is the easy Question";
const Question5H = " 5-This is the hard Question";
const Question6E = " 6-This is the easy Question";
const Question6H = " 6-This is the hard Question";
const Done = " DONE ";

let count = 1;
let question = null;
const scores = [];

const questions = {
  1: {
    intent: "Intent1",
    easy: Question1E,
    hard: Question1H,
  },
  2: {
    intent: "Intent2",
    easy: Question2E,
    hard: Question2H,
  },
  3: {
    intent: "Intent3",
    easy: Question3E,
    hard: Question3H,
  },
  4: {
    intent: "Intent4",
    easy: Question4E,
    hard: Question4H,
  },
  5: {
    intent: "Intent5",
    easy: Question5E,
    hard: Question5H,
  },
  6: {
    intent: "Intent6",
    easy: Question6E,
    hard: Question6H,
  },
};

function test() {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    test();
  }, 10000);

  const enter = document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      test();
    }
  });

  if (count < 6) {
    const currentquestion = questions[count];
    //IGNORE THIS PART
    if (count <= 1) {
      let randomizer = Math.random();
      randomizer <= 0.5 ?
        (question = currentquestion.easy) :
        (question = currentquestion.hard);
    } else {
      scores[scores.length - 1] >= 0.65 ?
        (question = currentquestion.hard) :
        (question = currentquestion.easy);
    }
    //CONTINUE HERE
    console.log(`${question}`);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log(`${Done}`);
  }
  count++;
}

test();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting a setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout)

Comment: Your timer const is in the scope of another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. timer needs to be outside the function
2. test needs to be its own function

```js
let timer;
const test = () => {

  if (count < 6) {
    const currentquestion = questions[count];
    //IGNORE THIS PART
    if (count <= 1) {
      let randomizer = Math.random();
      randomizer <= 0.5 ?
        (question = currentquestion.easy) :
        (question = currentquestion.hard);
    } else {
      scores[scores.length - 1] >= 0.65 ?
        (question = currentquestion.hard) :
        (question = currentquestion.easy);
    }
    //CONTINUE HERE
    console.log(`${question}`);
    timer = setTimeout(test, 2000); // set it to something shorter while testing  

  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log(Done);
  }
  count++;
};


const enter = document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    test()
  }
});
test(); // start
```

```html
<script>
  // moved the setup
  const Question1E = " 1-This is the easy Question";
  const Question1H = " 1-This is the hard Question";
  const Question2E = " 2-This is the easy Question";
  const Question2H = " 2-This is the hard Question";
  const Question3E = " 3-This is the easy Question";
  const Question3H = " 3-This is the hard Question";
  const Question4E = " 4-This is the easy Question";
  const Question4H = " 4-This is the hard Question";
  const Question5E = " 5-This is the easy Question";
  const Question5H = " 5-This is the hard Question";
  const Question6E = " 6-This is the easy Question";
  const Question6H = " 6-This is the hard Question";
  const Done = " DONE ";

  let count = 1;
  let question = null;
  const scores = [];

  const questions = {
    1: {
      intent: "Intent1",
      easy: Question1E,
      hard: Question1H,
    },
    2: {
      intent: "Intent2",
      easy: Question2E,
      hard: Question2H,
    },
    3: {
      intent: "Intent3",
      easy: Question3E,
      hard: Question3H,
    },
    4: {
      intent: "Intent4",
      easy: Question4E,
      hard: Question4H,
    },
    5: {
      intent: "Intent5",
      easy: Question5E,
      hard: Question5H,
    },
    6: {
      intent: "Intent6",
      easy: Question6E,
      hard: Question6H,
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: That unfortunately does not seem to work since it produces the same outcome

Comment: there is an issue, test does not start the timer again after updating the question

Comment: yes but with no timer

Comment: When the question change the timer should be started again (without hitting enter)

Comment: The Bot asks the first question -> Enter -> shows the second Question -> time passes -> 3rd question -> then it stops unless you press enter again

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again - but how would that work if I only wanted to change a variable within a certain time period? For Example  Variable that holds a boolean value - so after x Seconds turn variable y into false

Comment: Hard to tell what you mean

Comment: ok so let's say that I have a variable that determines whether an answer was sent within a certain scope of time. For example, the variable "legit" is set to true.  After a certain time ( i.e 5 seconds ) the l variable turns to false. Otherwise, just let it be true

Comment: Using a different timer?

Comment: yes that  is not related to the example from before - more a general question :)

Comment: Use a different timer: -  to set legit to false after 5 seconds: `let legit = true; let flagTimer = setTimeout(function() { legit = false },5000)` or do you want leave legit true if something else happens inside the 5 seconds?

Comment: nope that would be it :) thank you very much for your help :)