# How to reset and start setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I made an RT web app thanks to the online help and now I have not completed only one part which is not working well. When a function calls in every second and has new data then the color of the text should be "red" and after three seconds should return back to the same color. It works, if the value has not changed in every second, but when value is changing the things are not working well. The color of the value turns to the black and then red. It is not keeping the same value.
Real-Time update is working, the only thing is when there is a new data in every second the color not keeping the same color.

```
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
      fetch('/data_json').then(
        response => response.json()
      ).then(
        data =>
          data.forEach(match =>
            updateElement(match)
          )            
      )
    }, 1000
  );

function updateElement(match) {
    Object.entries(match).forEach(([k,v]) => {
      if(document.getElementById(k + '_' + match.id) != null){
        element = document.getElementById(k + '_' + match.id);
        previousValue = element.innerHTML;           
        // If Previous value is not equal to the new value, change it!
        if (previousValue !== v.toString()) {
            blinkUpdate(element, v.toString())
        }
      }                
                 
    })
}

function blinkUpdate(element, newValue, newColor='#FF2400') {

    previousColor = element.style.color;
    var start_Time=null;
    element.innerHTML = newValue;
    element.style.color = newColor; 
    if(newColor==previousColor){
      clearTimeout(start_Time)
    }else{
        // Set back to original color after timeout ms
      start_Time=setTimeout(() => {
        element.style.color = '#000000'
      }, 3000)
    }     
    
}
</script>
```

So the question is, how to reset the timer when there is a new call to the function? And new call should reset the timeout. And the color should remain the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting a setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you store `start_Time` timer reference inside the function. This reference is gone next time the function runs, so when you do `clearTimeout`, it is not clearing anything at all.

There is a completely diff way to implement this that would probably be better -- but I don't want to derail you so alternatively...

You could store the timers in a map against the id of the field outside the function, and reference these inside of it. This way you have a store of timers, each of them stored against the id of the element. So between each "tick" of the interval, you can reference the exact timer you want to cancel.

I think also, when new data arrives whilst it was red, you probably just want it to reset the 3 seconds? So it should both clear it and set it again.

```
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
      fetch('/data_json').then(
        response => response.json()
      ).then(
        data =>
          data.forEach(match =>
            updateElement(match)
          )            
      )
    }, 1000
  );

function updateElement(match) {
    Object.entries(match).forEach(([k,v]) => {
      if(document.getElementById(k + '_' + match.id) != null){
        element = document.getElementById(k + '_' + match.id);
        previousValue = element.innerHTML;           
        // If Previous value is not equal to the new value, change it!
        if (previousValue !== v.toString()) {
            blinkUpdate(element, v.toString())
        }
      }                
                 
    })
}


const timers = {}
function blinkUpdate(element, newValue, newColor='#FF2400') {

    previousColor = element.style.color;
    var start_Time=null;
    element.innerHTML = newValue;
    element.style.color = newColor; 
    if(timers[element.id] && previousColor !== newColor){
        clearTimeout(timers[element.id])
    }

      // Set back to original color after timeout ms
      timers[element.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        element.style.color = '#000000'
        delete timers[element.id]
      }, 3000)     
    
}
</script>
```